# Calendar in Org Mode

Tags: org-mode, calendar

I am using Emacs Org Mode to manage a todo list. Is it possible to use Emacs to manage my calendar?

I will need it to integrate with my Nextcloud calendar. And it would be great if it can integrate with my todo list in Org Mode.

If this is already answered in a way a newbie like me can understand, please just point me to it. I looked up a few sources/ answers but could not make anything of them.

Comment: I run my small business using Emacs to manage my tasks and events and it was one of the main reasons for initially switching to Emacs.  Without getting into synchronizing with the cloud (since there are several options), you may wish to check-out `calfw` for a pretty calendar view that fills the entire buffer.  Although not many people seem to request it, I am rather fond of the 12-month custom view that I created using the built-in calendar library -- it is either here on stackexchange, or over at stackoverflow.  You can color code events/tasks that appear on the 3/12 month rotating calendar.

Comment: @lawlist Again, a newbie question.How do I check out calfw? I looked up `M-x list-packages` But it does not show any calfw :(

Comment: It may be helpful to do some Googling for how to identify and adjust your `load-path`, and where to manually save optional libraries, and using the proper `require` statement in your `.emacs` or `init.el` file, and checking to see that the library being added has the correct filename and a proper `provide` statement at the bottom.  There is surely a an Emacs wiki page about the `load-path`, and you'll find several examples of how to add optional libraries.  A ton of goodies are not available through `list-packages`.  There are some additional sources that can be added to the package database.

Answer (score 2):

I use org-mode together with https://github.com/dengste/org-caldav to sync with google calendar. The readme of `org-caldav` states that Nextcloud is regularly tested, so it sounds like it would work.

Below are the commands I use (from `bash`) to install my packages from scratch, including the newest `org-mode` and `org-caldav`. **Warning!** The `rm` command deletes all `org-*` packages that you may have installed locally (i.e. not system-wide). It is necessary if you wish to upgrade `org-mode` itself, but perhaps not if you just want to install `org-caldav`.

```
rm -rf ~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-* # your installation path _may_ vary.
emacs -Q -batch -eval "(progn (require 'package) (add-to-list 'package-archives '(\"org\" . \"http://orgmode.org/elpa/\"))  (package-initialize) (package-refresh-contents) (package-install 'org-plus-contrib))"
emacs -batch --eval "(progn (require 'package) (package-initialize) (message (format \"Org version is: %s.\" (org-version))))"
emacs -Q -batch -eval "(progn (require 'package) (add-to-list 'package-archives '(\"melpa\" . \"https://melpa.org/packages/\"))  (package-initialize) (package-refresh-contents) (package-install 'paradox))"
emacs -Q -batch -eval "(progn (require 'package) (add-to-list 'package-archives '(\"melpa\" . \"https://melpa.org/packages/\"))  (package-initialize) (package-refresh-contents) (package-install 'use-package))"
```

Skip the last command if you do not want to use `use-package`. After the above, run `paradox-list-packages` and install `org-caldav`.

Comment: Thanks. It seems very interesting. However, how do I install it? Where? I did M-x list-packages and it did not show me org-caldav.

Comment: I think I installed it using paradox.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the bash commands I use to install org-mode and paradox.

Comment: Please be very careful about giving a newbie an `rm` command, as well as inexperienced computer users who will read this thread in the future after a Google search.  Otherwise, you may see future comments from people in a state of panic asking you why X, Y and Z are no longer on the computer ... :)

Comment: @NiclasBörlin Thanks. I did it differently. Added the following lines to my `~/.emacs`. `(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))
` And `M-x list-packages` to install `org-caldav` The next ballte is to actually use the package. :)

Comment: @lawlist indeed! :) And it could have been me!! But with these lines in my `~/.emacs` I should be OK now.

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't think of that. As far as I understand it, the <code>rm</code> command is necessary if you want to upgrade <code>org-mode</code> itself, but perhaps not otherwise. Anyway, I have updated my answer with a warning and a motivation for the <code>rm</code> command.

Comment: @NiclasBörlin Some progress. But still not there. In my `~/.emacs` there are these lines: `(setq org-caldav-url "https://cloud.some.org/remote.php/dav/calendars/user")
(setq org-caldav-calendar-id "org-testing")
(setq org-caldav-inbox "~/Documents/organize/org-mode/org-testing.org")
(setq org-caldav-files org-agenda-files)`. Things sync very well in one direction: Caldav -> Org. But even after I enter an event in org-testing.org and `M-x org-caldav-sync` it does not get transferred to the server. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @deshmukh Sorry, I don't know the code enough (as in: not at all) and I sync to google calendar, I have no idea if you should look at your org config, nextcloud config, or the syncing code. I do know that if you want to debug the caldav code, you could do the following: 1) C-h f org-caldav-sync to bring up the help. 2) Click on org-caldav.el to bring up the source. 3) M-x edebug-defun to set a breakpoint at the start of the function. Now call up org-caldav-sync "as usual" and single-step through the debugger. For help on edebug, see the Edebug menu.

Comment: Some googling showed me  http://www.zvon.org/other/elisp/Output/SEC217.html as well. Your mileage may wary.

Comment: Oh yes, and I did find a reference to org-caldav-debug-level. I would start by setting it to 2 (excessive). And of course, test on non-critical data.

Comment: Some debugging on my own resulted in https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1274. If you use magit, you could try (setq vc-handled-backends nil).

Comment: @NiclasBörlin Thanks. But I am just starting out in terms of using Emacs. Frankly, I did not understand most of what you had referred to. :( I guess I will either try another package to sync or else will live with no calendar in Emacs Org Mode :(